# How to get the PID of an external program (invoked by MATLAB) via MATLAB commands?

Tags: windows, matlab, pid

I am curious how to get the PID of an external program invoked by MATLAB (in Windows).

For instance, I invoke a notepad in MATLAB via the command ***!notepad.exe*** or ***system('notepad.exe')***. I want to obtain the PID of this notepad immediately once it is invoked.

Since multiple notepads might be open at the same time on one computer, I need to get their respective PIDs (instead of the process name) to keep track of them. I have no clue how it can be implemented....

looking for help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Creation date not needed

You can call Windows' [`tasklist`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist) command from Matlab using [`system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html), and then parse the results:

```
name = 'notepad.exe';
[~, s] = system(['tasklist /FI "imagename eq ' name '"']);
result = regexp(s, ['(?<=' strrep(name, '.', '\.') '\s*)\d+'], 'match');
result = str2double(result); % convert to numbers if needed
```

The result of `system` is of the following form (two Notepad windows open; Spanish Windows version):

```
>> s
s =
    '
     Nombre de imagen               PID Nombre de sesión Núm. de ses Uso de memor
     ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
     notepad.exe                  12576 Console                    1    13,488 KB
     notepad.exe                  13860 Console                    1    13,484 KB
    '
```

So the regular expression searches for digits preceded by the program name and optional spaces, to give the final result

```
>> result =
          12576       13860
```

---

## Creation date needed

If you need to **filter based on creation date**, you can use Windows' [`wmic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic):

```
name = 'notepad.exe';
[~, s] = system(['wmic process where name=''' name ''' get ProcessId, CreationDate']);
```

This gives a string such as

```
s =
    'CreationDate               ProcessId  
     20191015151243.876221+120  6656       
     20191015151246.092357+120  4004       

     '
```

The `CreationDate` is in the [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/wmisdk/cim-datetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN) `yyyymmddHHMMSS+UUU`, where `+UUU` or `-UUU` is number of minutes from UTC.

You can parse `s` into a cell array of strings as follows:

```
result = reshape(regexp(s, '[\d+\.]+', 'match').', 2, []).'; % 2 is the number of columns
```

This gives

```
result =
  2×2 cell array
    {'20191015151243.876221+120'}    {'6656'}
    {'20191015151246.092357+120'}    {'4004'}
```

Then you can filter based on the first columnn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any way to retrieve the start time of each process? I need that to filter out the undesired processes.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Not with `tasklist`, as far as I know; but `wmic` seems to work. Please see edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Create a Powershell script, *findPid.ps1*, containing the following:

```
Get-Process | Where {$_.ProcessName -eq "notepad"} | Sort-Object starttime -Descending | Select 'Id'
```

The script above gets the information on the running notepad processes, filters them by time and extracts the pid.

---

Execute a non-blocking system call from MATLAB:

```
system('notepad.exe &')
```

Call the Powershell script:

```
[~,pids] = system('powershell -file findPid.ps1');
```

**pids** is a char vector containing the pids of the notepad.exe process (or processes).

So to obtain the most recent pid:

```
pid = regexp(pids,'Id\n[^-]+--\n([0-9]+)','tokens','once')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, Powershell does not work well in my computer, I am wondering if the same functionalities can be implemented via MS-Dos, e.g., 'tasklist', to include the start time of processes as well?

Comment: I tried your script on others' computer with Win 10, and it can work. But when I used it in my Win 7, I have no idea why I always need to press 'Enter' key in MATLAB to continue the script, since it seems MATLAB is waiting for some action after executing '***[~,pids] = system('powershell -file findPid.ps1');***'....it is weird

Comment: Uhm, same MATLAB versions on Win 10 and Win 7? At what stage do you have to press the Enter key?

Comment: Yes, same MATLAB R2018b. For ***[~,pids] = system('powershell -file findPid.ps1');***, I need the Enter key for continuation.

Comment: No idea, I can't reproduce. Try restarting MATLAB.