# Waiting for closing of previously started program

Tags: windows, matlab

I would like to ask you how to specify waiting for closing of specific program which was started before. I am showing here an example with command waitfor but unfortunately I don't know how to write it correctly, therefore I am asking you for help.

```
system('"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" &');
waitfor "closing of chrome.exe"
```

Comment: the `&` in the system command is telling it to not wait. If you remove it, what happens?

Comment: the & symbol has to be there, because sometimes starting of external program like chrome.exe fails, and after system command I am checking whether it was started or not. In case it was not started, I am restarting it. In case it was started I want to wait for its finish. Unfortunately I am not able to specify it correctly, so I am asking you for help. Instead of chrome.exe I am starting external solver which lasts aproximately for 40 minutes.

Comment: I think you may want then to sleep your code for a while (e.g. 10 seconds, 1 minute etc) and check if some output file/variable has been created as end state.

Comment: Can you help how to specify command for waiting for creation of specific file (for example "file.db")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the advice [in this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58392176/7328782) to find the PID of the new program right after you start it. Then, in a loop, check to see if that PID is still running (using again the same process as before), and `pause(1)` to avoid checking too frequently.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do something like:

```
time_in_seconds=60
while ~isfile("output_folder/file.db")
   pause(time_in_seconds)
end
```

Note that this program, as is, requires that file to exist at some point, otherwise infinite loop. Make sure you put safeguards to end it in case the file does not get created (like a time limit).

But I am not sure it makes sense to have MATLAB waiting for 40 minutes for a script to finish...